# acceleration of theta function evaluation for Newton's method fractal generation

Tags: optimization, fractals

I have been trying to generate [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal) fractals of [Jacobi theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) -- my attempts with mpmath take a long time, so I tried coding it in C.

The source used to generate the following image is here: http://owen.maresh.info/allegra.c and will compile with a *gcc allegra.c -o allegra -lm* and then should be invoked as ./allegra > jacobi.pnm

[image]
<sub>(source: [maresh.info](http://owen.maresh.info/jacobi.png))</sub>

so:
* Are there ways that I can speed up evaluation -- this took over a half hour of wall time to produce this image? (I would like to be able to produce these images quickly with different nomes so that I can make a movie)
* I know that I'm making a mistake in the theta function definition, but I'm having difficulty finding the cause of the discontinuities.

For reference purposes, this image was produced by doing the standard Newton's method on ϑ<sub>3</sub>(z,0.001-0.3019*i)

Comment: do you mind if I pass your code to apple as an example application that runs slower when compiled with their new `clang` C  compiler than with their gcc.

Comment: Not a problem. I'm going to try this with icc in a bit.

Comment: `icc` is a great idea. I curious how much improvement you see with it over `gcc`.

Comment: icc » /usr/bin/time ./allegra2 >> chack.pnm
164.21user 1.35system 2:46.03elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 14864maxresident)k
0inputs+4920outputs (0major+985minor)pagefaults 0swaps
owen@orrery ~/math/thenewt » md5sum chack.pnm
03b3ed17194d6e77970310bce55c967d  chack.pnm
gcc » /usr/bin/time ./allegra >> geese.pnm
1257.28user 23.44system 21:32.45elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15376maxresident)k
32inputs+4920outputs (0major+1010minor)pagefaults 0swaps
owen@orrery ~/math/thenewt » md5sum geese.pnm 
03b3ed17194d6e77970310bce55c967d  geese.pnm

Comment: Wow. `icc` produced code that ran over 7x faster than gcc is impressive. (Also thanks for mentioning icc, I hadn't realized intel makes their development tools available free for noncommercial use on Linux).

Comment: addendum: I finished the render, which is viewable on youtube here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0ZGfCmPjWA and the next step is to try using the intel math kernel library (under the assumption that it's going to be faster than math.h)

Answer (score 3):

First try enabling compiler optimizations with `-O3` and/or `-fast`.  A quick test on my system showed a factor or 3 performance improvement

Also, when experimenting with code changes to improve performance, it is beneficial to have a quicker runtime, perhaps by changing your main loop to `for(a=0;a<10 /* 512*/ ;a++)`

Also note: GCC supports [complex numbers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html) and see man pages `complex`, `cpow`,  and `cexp` and include file `/usr/include/complex.h`

I profiled the application, and saw it is spending most of the time in `powc()`.  Unfortunately when I changed powc() to use `cpow()` from the math library, it ran slower than your implementation.

If the system you are running on has multiple cores, wall clock time could probably be brought down fairly easily by parallelizing the outer main-loop with OpenMP.  However, when you are generating image frames for the animation, it will likely be most efficient to just have each frame being generated with a separate process  (I like `xargs -P # -n 1` for this type of coarse grain parallelization.)

Comment: Incidentally, it's my gut feeling that nobody is actually using the complex datatypes in the c99 standard for anything, and that it just got added onto the language because someone thought it would be a good idea at the time. (as a double aside: I am sort of agitating for a special functions ASIC because these functions (Jacobi) theta get reimplemented agazillion times in software and all the software implementations are sloooow)

Comment: I thought `gcc` had complex support for a while before c99.  However, I wouldn't be surprised if most of the heavy-duty users of `complex` are still using fortran.

Answer (score 3):

When you mentioned this on IRC, I was in an odd mood and spent a while optimizing it.  It's now at least 4x faster on my Mac, not counting compiler optimization flags, more so on some other platforms.

I am...ignorant when it comes to higher math, but I do know a few things about optimization.  I believe the computation in this is the same as the original, apart from substituting the system cexp() for your implementation in expc(), and it produces identical output.  You get to decide whether it's still numerically stable enough for you.

As noted by Brian Swift, powc() is expensive, and that's because of the log() and pow() functions

The things that were big wins:

- the computation in pjtheta() and pjtheta3() can be combined
- that computation can be made an inner loop in newt(), and some of it can be moved out of the inner or both loops
- cpow() may be slower for Brian (and me), but cexp() is definitely faster than your code, at least on my machines.  try them both ways
- -ffast-math in the compiler flags removes support for standards compliance with ill behaved numbers and speeds things up a lot

Another big win was converting the arithmetic in cexp() and cpow() to single-precision, but that produced slightly different results, which you may or may not care about.

You may not recognize the program any more, but it's at:

https://github.com/cgull/allegra.git

I noticed a couple more things and knocked another 25%-33% out of it (gosh, it's an iterative function that converges!)

I'm sure that someone who understands higher math better than I could find another 2-4x of performance in there...